# Bitcoin API with mixing service

Tags: api, mixing

I'm looking for an API that can hide where my received money goes, for privacy reasons. I don't want my customers to be able to see how much money I've received.

Blockchain used to have a mixing service with their receiving API, so that no one could see where the bitcoin was forwarded to, but they discontinued it. Are there any API's out there that have a mixing feature like this? If not, what can I do to ensure privacy?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use a hierarchial wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Bitmixer.io, it even has an [API](https://bitmixer.io/api.html).

You could do that, but personally, I think it's a much better idea to generate a new wallet per customer transaction. That way, all your coins aren't grouped together, so the customers won't know how much you make. Just how much they paid. Personally, my app creates addresses through the [Coinbase API](https://developers.coinbase.com/api), all of which are held in a specific account named after my app.

Comment: I'll look into Bitmixer. About generating new wallets, what about when I feel it's time to cash out? It would be troublesome to withdraw from hundreds of wallets.

Comment: @user3893623, actually, since using the Coinbase API required you to have a Coinbase wallet, you could log into the web interface and operate it like you would any other web wallet. Click "send" and type in the entire amount you'd like to send. Coinbase will also give you notifications when payments are for your wallets triggered via callbacks that your app can parse. Don't forget to mark this question as answered if it is!